# How to keep Xcode class in sync with other projects

Tags: xcode, git

I have a single class with all handy code snippets I use all the time in every projects. What I would like to do is keep that single class in sync with other projects in Xcode.

Example:

I have two projects both with the "general class". I open Project A and add some code to the "general class". Then when I open project B it will be there too.

Is this possible in anyway? Can this be done with Git?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I used the solution below to solve it

1. Copied all classes to be shared in a folder out of any project.
2. Added that folder into different projects (using git) by right-clicking in the project navigator and choosing "Add Files to " without creating a local copy.

For example I have the following folders:

- DataAccessLayer- contains C++ class to acces to the DB
- BusinessLayer- All C++ core business classes of my applications
- iOS- All iOS interface classes and a wrapper for C++ classes
- XOS- All iOS interface classes and a wrapper for C++ classes

In the last 2 folders are projects which use same clases. When I edit a file from a project the change is reflected in the other projects

I hope this will help you

Comment: Example added. Thanks Andy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cocoapods for that. Create podspec, then add it into Podfile of all projects as local dependency by "pod MyLib, :path => '~/path/to' ". See more https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#specification

Answer (score 0):

Git submodules are another clean way of doing this. The submodule will be seen as a directory in multiple projects, and you can push changes to it as it is also a git repository. See https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/ CocoaPods are another good option, but require you learning about how to make CocoaPods.